# No applicable method 'Parse' exists in type 'DateTime'

Tags: c#, datetime, dynamic-linq

I get the exception "No applicable method 'Parse' exists in type 'DateTime'"  when I run the following code:

```
var truncatedData = new object();
string TableName = "Products";
string ColumnName = cboAdvSearchCol1.Text.ToString();
var rawData = twr.GetType().GetProperty(TableName).GetValue(twr, null);
string query = ColumnName + ">= DateTime.Parse(" + txtAdvSearchVal1.Text +") && " + ColumnName + "< DateTime.Parse("
+ txtAdvSearchVal1.Text +").AddDays(1)";
truncatedData = ((IQueryable<object>)rawData).Where(query).ToList();//I get exception here
```

while debugging, I get the value of (string) query as `"RUNTIMESTAMP>= DateTime.Parse(7/30/2015) && RUNTIMESTAMP< DateTime.Parse(7/30/2015).AddDays(1)"` Please note that I am using dynamic linq.

Comment: Not familiar with dynamic LINQ, but doesn't `7/30/2015` have to be in quotes for it to be valid for `Parse` since that takes a `string`?

Comment: I tried by putting quotes too, didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You generate the following code for your dynamic expression: `DateTime.Parse(7/30/2015)`. However, it's not doing what you're expecting.

Since there are no quotes surrounding the date, the expression `7 / 30 / 2015` is interpreted as integer division, like this:

```
7 / 30 / 2015 = (7 / 30) / 2015 = 0 / 2015 = 0
```

So, the result is the same as `DateTime.Parse(0)`, but `DateTime.Parse` only accepts `string` as an argument. Since a method accepting an `int` is not found, you get the exception about no applicable method.

The correct way to call it would be:

```
string query = ColumnName + ">= DateTime.Parse(\"" + txtAdvSearchVal1.Text +"\") && "
    + ColumnName + "< DateTime.Parse(\"" + txtAdvSearchVal1.Text +"\").AddDays(1)";
```

Notice the extra `"` symbols to use the date as a string.

Comment: I tried that before posting here, it didn't work either. In this case it gives exception: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. Also, the query forms like this: "RUNTIMESTAMP>= DateTime.Parse(\"7/30/2015\") && RUNTIMESTAMP< DateTime.Parse(\"7/30/2015\").AddDays(1)"

Comment: @Paradox, yes, that's a different error, which I think has been answered before in the site. I don't remember the details, but basically it means that LINQ to Entities doesn't know how to map the method to a SQL query.